# Firebase data not able to get immediately

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, realm

I don't know why when I try to call getFromRealm() I can't retrieve it on the first time, in order to get the data I have to close and re-open the app. 
Am I doing it in the wrong way? I have tried by using Sqlite, but they are having the same problem. Anyone can help? 
My goals is to get data immediately and retrieve on the spot. 
Below is the code.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
public String mName;
public String mEmail;
private Realm mRealm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRealm = Realm.getInstance(this);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    saveToRealm();
    getFromRealm();
    Log.d(TAG, "Name: " + mName); // Here show null at first open the app
    Log.d(TAG, "Email: " + mEmail); // Here show null at first open the app
 }
}
```

This is save data to Realm method:

```
 public void saveToRealm() {
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Users details = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(dataSnapshot));

            String name = details.getName();
            String email = details.getEmail();

            details.setName(name);
            details.setEmail(email);

            mRealm.beginTransaction();
            mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(details);
            mRealm.commitTransaction();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    };
    mDatabase.child("User")
            .child("Details")
            .addValueEventListener(postListener);
}
```

This is the get data method:

```
 public void getFromRealm() {
    RealmResults<Users> results =
            mRealm.where(Users.class).findAll();

    try{
        Users c = results.get(0);
        mName = c.getName();
        mEmail = c.getEmail();

       } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e));
    }
}
```

This is the object class:

```
public class Users extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private long id;

private String name;
private String email;

public Users() {
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
```

}

Comment: What version of Realm is this? `Realm.getInstance(Context)` was removed ages ago in favor of `RealmConfiguration.Builder()`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Since i have the same issue by using sqlite. Will the versioning affect my expected results? I quite new in realm btw.

Comment: Well 0.89.0 had some severe breaking changes, but if you go 0.89.0 you may as well go 1.1.1 (or 1.2.0)

Comment: Cool, I will try on it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve data from where you are store something like this..

```
public void saveToRealm() {
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Users details = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(dataSnapshot));

            String name = details.getName();
            String email = details.getEmail();

            details.setName(name);
            details.setEmail(email);

            mRealm.beginTransaction();
            mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(details);
            mRealm.commitTransaction();

            getFromRealm();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    };
    mDatabase.child("User")
            .child("Details")
            .addValueEventListener(postListener);
}
```

As it will take someTime like seconds to get Data from firebase data so retrieve data after only whenever you store.

Try to get your data like this way..

```
public void getFromRealm() { 
    RealmResults<Users> results = mRealm.where(Users.class).findAll();
        try {
               for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){

                 mName = results.get(i).getName();
                 mEmail = results.get(i).getEmail();

            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e)); 
      } 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when i try to do Log.d(TAG, mName); outside the method saveToRealm() it still remain null.

Comment: Then make sure you are getting data from firebase?

Comment: I can get it from firebase, i got do log inside the method, but when i try to get after the method it is null.

Comment: See my Updated answer and remove `getFromRealm()` Method from `onCreate` and call it from inside the `saveToRealm()` as I suggested in my answer.